# how to store formatted text in sql? or how to retrieve formatted text from sql?

Tags: sql, vb.net, richtextbox

I will copy some content from word which have specific font. Then i will paste those contents in rich text box.After that i will save it to sql server.
The solution i need is when i retrieve those contents from front-end i need those contents to display with the same font which i had when i save it.
what to do? If there is any solution please let me know guys.

Comment: With the SaveFile method, you can save the data in a steam. Then you can store that in binary format on the database.

Comment: The Rtf property of the RichTextBox is a string property that holds all of the display information.

Answer (score 0):

Text is text.  "Formatting" (including "font" and/or "font family") can be any of a million different things.

SUGGESTIONS:

- You might consider saving your "text" column as HTML, and then have a separate "CSS" column to define the "attributes" (including, but not limited to, "font").
- You might also consider saving your text in a simple [markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/getting-started) language.
- There are lots of other options, depending on your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, and to make it easy on yourself, is to us a bindingsource.

```
        Imports System.Data.SqlClient

        Public Class BindingExamples
            Dim DtTable As New DataTable
            Dim TableBS As New BindingSource
            Private Sub BindingExamples_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

                Using SqlConn As New SqlConnection("Connection String")
                    Using TableDA As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLE", SqlConn)
                        TableDA.Fill(DtTable)
                        TableBS.DataSource = DtTable
                    End Using
                End Using

                RichTextBox1.DataBindings.Add("RTF", TableBS, "TextColumn", True)

            End Sub

            Private Sub ButtonUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonUpdate.Click

                Using SqlConn As New SqlConnection("Connection String")
                    Using TableDA As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLE", SqlConn)
                        Using TableCB As New SqlCommandBuilder(TableDA)
                            TableBS.EndEdit
                            TableDA.Update(DtTable)
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using

            End Sub
        End Class
```